# Ошибка "identifier ofstream is undefind"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

C++!? Ошибка в программе, прога по идее должна делать get запрос к сайту, исп. WinInet?

Хочу научиться делать запросы в C++, использовал материал для обучения из [этой статьи](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/inet/wininet.xml), отчеканив 1-ый исходник столкнулся с 1-й проблемой, вы ее можете прочитать в комменте, вот эта строка

```
ofstream fnews("news.html",ios::out|ios::binary);
```

так что не так в программе, как ее все-таки запустить, то что переменная кривая какая-то, это я понимаю, но не понимаю, почему и что с этим делать, вот тот самый 1-ый исходник:

```
// #include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinInet.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"wininet")

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    bool ok = false;

    // инициализируем WinInet
    HINTERNET hInternet =
        ::InternetOpen(
               TEXT("WinInet Test"),
               INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,
               NULL,NULL,
               0);
 if (hInternet != NULL) {
      // открываем HTTP сессию
      HINTERNET hConnect = 
          ::InternetConnectA(
               hInternet,
               TEXT("www.rsdn.ru"),
               INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT,
               NULL,NULL,
               INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,
               0,
               1u);
 if (hConnect != NULL) {
      // открываем запрос
      HINTERNET hRequest = 
          ::HttpOpenRequestA(
               hConnect,
               TEXT("GET"),
               TEXT("news.asp"),
               NULL,
               NULL,
               0,
               INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION,
               1);
 if (hRequest != NULL) {
      // посылаем запрос
      BOOL bSend = ::HttpSendRequestA(hRequest, NULL,0,NULL,0);
      if (bSend) {
          // создаем выходной файл
          // [ В ЭТОЙ СТРОКЕ ОШИБКА : Error'identifier ofstream is undefind' ]
          ofstream fnews("news.html",ios::out|ios::binary);
          if (fnews.is_open()) for (;;) {
               // читаем данные
               char szData[1024];
               DWORD dwBytesRead;
               BOOL bRead = 
                   ::InternetReadFile(
                      hRequest,
                      szData,sizeof(szData)-1,
                      &dwBytesRead);
    // выход из цикла при ошибке или завершении
    if (bRead == FALSE || dwBytesRead == 0) 
        break;

    // сохраняем результат
    szData[dwBytesRead] = 0;
    fnews << szData;

    ok = true;

    } 
   }
  // закрываем запрос
      ::InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
  }
  // закрываем сессию
 ::InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
 }
 // закрываем WinInet
 ::InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
}
 // для полного счастья, запускаем считанную страничку
 if (ok)
     system("start news.html");
 return 0;
}
```

Работаю в среде Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express

Comment: не знаю даже какой ответ лучшим выбрать, тут эксперты нужны чтобы разобраться что лучше "общий namespace std или под бит т.с."

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте пространство имен std:

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ofstream fnews("news.html", ios::out|ios::binary);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Товарищи,

```
std::ofstream fnews("news.html",std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);
```

лучше чем:

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Почему? Тут неоднозначностью даже и не пахнет. А пространства имён сделаны с целью избегания неоднозначности.

 Я считаю, что using namespace можно не бояться использовать везде кроме заголовочников.

Comment: что за ... не ну я понимаю что программы обновляются, все в жизни меняется, но как тогда учиться кодить вообще???, наверно нужно работать в майкрософт, мы же за ними не успеваем!? Следующая ошибка в программе на в той же строке оказалось, опять сбой пространства имен, смотрим: http://i40.tinypic.com/20fvqjk.jpg

Comment: @GLmonster: потому что "using namespace x" плохой "coding practice"

@Tolbase: std::ios::in | std::ios:binary

Comment: ага, godplusplus, тебе "+", coding practice не плохой, а просто процесс идет!

Comment: >потому что "using namespace x" плохой "coding practice"

 И почему же так? Не могу придумать ни одну ситуацию, когда это могло бы привести к багам в программе. Когда всё однозначно, проблем не возникает, а когда - нет, происходит ошибка компиляции, которая исправляется уточнением пространства имён.

 А если using namespace плохо использовать, то зачем тогда его сделали? И зачем вообще тогда нужны пространства имён? Можно было бы тогда писать std_string, std_vector и т. д..

 В C# все используют `using`, аналогичный `using namespace` из C++, и всё нормально.

Comment: В таком случае не будет проблем в использовании "using namespace X", так как это только одно пространство имен, но я думаю, что лучше сделать по-другому, особенно для новичков потому что:
- избежишь проблем в будущем, когда будет много пространств имен, 
- легче найти в коде, когда он используется (поиск "std::" решает это, по той же самой причине лучше использовать  static_cast и dynamic_cast вместо C/C++ style cast)